# Android: Header image under Notification bar

Tags: android, header, material-design

I have been wondering how to achieve the effect where your header images comes beneath the translucent notification bar in android. Like the effect in the below given image:

[image]

I have somewhat same looking view but my header is not overlapping the notification bar. How can I achieve this effect?

Any help or suggestion would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Which Language are you working on ? HTML ?

Comment: Sorry @Ahsan. I forgot to mention Android in there.